# Grab everything after character if its present

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that grabs the suburb from a string that usually contains a suburb and industry in the format:

```
INDUSTRY - SUBURB
```

Sometimes the string may not contain the `INDUSTRY -` part and just have the suburb. In this case my regular expression fails to grab anything.

Is there a way to make the regex robust enough to grab everything after the hypen *if its present* otherwise just grab everything?

The following regex doesn't work: `(- |^)(.*)(,|$)`

The result is: `dvertising - Roseville Chase`

Comment: Why don't you just split the string on " - "?  (space dash space)

Comment: @RobertHarvey my program uses Regex for string manipulation. Using other methods is possible but I want to maintain consistency

Comment: Maybe you ought to learn some regex then.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `(.*)`, use `([^-]*)`:

```
(- |^)([^-]*)(,|$)
```

In action:

```
import re

re.search(r"(- |^)([^-]*)(,|$)", "Advertising - Roseville Chase").group(2)
Out[97]: 'Roseville Chase'

re.search(r"(- |^)([^-]*)(,|$)", "Roseville Chase").group(2)
Out[98]: 'Roseville Chase'
```

*More explanation was requested:

[^-] means "any character except for -".  By using [^-], you are making it impossible for the regex to match the entire string if there is a hyphen present.  It will have to match everything after the hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

Have two groups: one for the industry plus hyphen, and one for the suburb. Make the industry group optional with a question mark.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([^-]*-)?(.*)")
pattern.match("Advertising - Roseville Chase").group(2)
pattern.match("Amityville").group(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... it's much easier to do this **not** using a regex, I have to sit and grok the other answers and that's not what Python's about - I agree with Robert.

I'd just go for:

```
def suburb_or_all(text):
    industry, hyphen_present, suburb = text.partition(' - ')
    return suburb if hypen_present else text
```

Completely readable, self-documenting and remarkably efficient.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this: `(?<=-\s)(.*)` which would return everything after the `-`.  You can try it out [here](http://pythex.org/).[image: example]